# Azure Devops YAML Pipeline Tasks: Difference between NuGetToolInstaller@0 and NuGetToolInstaller@1

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've just looked at the online documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines to work out the difference between [NuGetToolInstaller@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/nuget-tool-installer-v0?view=azure-pipelines) and [NuGetToolInstaller@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/nuget-tool-installer-v1?view=azure-pipelines).

The explanations look virtually identical so the differences are not obvious.

Can anyone explain what the differences are and why you would use one and not the other?

Also there appear to be a lot more 'Inputs' than are listed here e.g. nugetConfigPath, verbosity, nuGetVersion and nuGetPath.

Does anyone know of a comprehensive reference for pipeline tasks as the ones I have found are incomplete and not necessarily clear.

Thanks

Comment: They are different. See my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

To summarize, there are only two differences:

***1. The structure of the task (it doesn't matter at all, just the location is different).***

***2. The underlying implementation of the task (this is very important, there is a section of the underlying code that is completely different.).***

Since the code is open source, I paste the code on the below to make it simpler for you to read.

## NuGetToolInstaller@0

```
import * as taskLib from 'azure-pipelines-task-lib/task';
import * as semver from 'semver';
import * as path from "path";
import * as peParser from "packaging-common/pe-parser";
import {VersionInfo} from "packaging-common/pe-parser/VersionResource";
import * as telemetry from "utility-common/telemetry";

import nuGetGetter = require("packaging-common/nuget/NuGetToolGetter");

async function run() {
    let nugetVersion: string;
    let checkLatest: boolean;
    let nuGetPath: string;
    let msbuildSemVer: semver.SemVer;
    try {
        taskLib.setResourcePath(path.join(__dirname, "task.json"));

        let versionSpec = taskLib.getInput('versionSpec', false);
        if (!versionSpec) {
            msbuildSemVer = await nuGetGetter.getMSBuildVersion();
            if (msbuildSemVer && semver.gte(msbuildSemVer, '16.8.0')) {
                taskLib.debug('Defaulting to 5.8.0 for msbuild version: ' + msbuildSemVer);
                versionSpec = '5.8.0';
            } else if (msbuildSemVer && semver.gte(msbuildSemVer, '16.5.0')) {
                taskLib.debug('Defaulting to 4.8.2 for msbuild version: ' + msbuildSemVer);
                versionSpec = '4.8.2';
            } else {
                versionSpec = '4.3.0';
            }
        }
        checkLatest = taskLib.getBoolInput('checkLatest', false);
        nuGetPath = await nuGetGetter.getNuGet(versionSpec, checkLatest, true);

        const nugetVersionInfo: VersionInfo = await peParser.getFileVersionInfoAsync(nuGetPath);
        if (nugetVersionInfo && nugetVersionInfo.fileVersion){
            nugetVersion = nugetVersionInfo.fileVersion.toString();
        }

    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error('ERR:' + error.message);
        taskLib.setResult(taskLib.TaskResult.Failed, "");
    } finally {
        _logNugetToolInstallerStartupVariables(nugetVersion, checkLatest, nuGetPath, msbuildSemVer);
    }
}

function _logNugetToolInstallerStartupVariables(
    nugetVersion: string,
    checkLatest: boolean,
    nuGetPath: string,
    msbuildSemVer: semver.SemVer) {
    try {
        const telem = {
            "NUGET_EXE_TOOL_PATH_ENV_VAR": taskLib.getVariable(nuGetGetter.NUGET_EXE_TOOL_PATH_ENV_VAR),
            "isCheckLatestEnabled": checkLatest,
            "requestedNuGetVersionSpec": taskLib.getInput('versionSpec', false),
            "nuGetPath": nuGetPath,
            "nugetVersion": nugetVersion,
            "msBuildVersion": msbuildSemVer && msbuildSemVer.toString()
        };
        telemetry.emitTelemetry("Packaging", "NuGetToolInstaller", telem);
    } catch (err) {
        taskLib.debug(`Unable to log NuGet Tool Installer task init telemetry. Err:(${err})`);
    }
}

run();
```

## NuGetToolInstaller@1

```
import * as taskLib from 'azure-pipelines-task-lib/task';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as nuGetGetter from 'packaging-common/nuget/NuGetToolGetter';
import * as peParser from "packaging-common/pe-parser";
import {VersionInfo} from "packaging-common/pe-parser/VersionResource";
import * as telemetry from "utility-common/telemetry";

const DEFAULT_NUGET_VERSION = '>=4.9';

async function run() {
    let nugetVersion: string;
    let checkLatest: boolean;
    let nuGetPath: string;
    let msBuildSemVer: string;
    try {
        taskLib.setResourcePath(path.join(__dirname, 'task.json'));

        const versionSpec = taskLib.getInput('versionSpec', false) || DEFAULT_NUGET_VERSION;
        checkLatest = taskLib.getBoolInput('checkLatest', false);
        nuGetPath = await nuGetGetter.getNuGet(versionSpec, checkLatest, true);

        const nugetVersionInfo: VersionInfo = await peParser.getFileVersionInfoAsync(nuGetPath);
        if (nugetVersionInfo && nugetVersionInfo.fileVersion){
            nugetVersion = nugetVersionInfo.fileVersion.toString();
        }

        msBuildSemVer = await nuGetGetter.getMSBuildVersionString();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('ERR:' + error.message);
        taskLib.setResult(taskLib.TaskResult.Failed, '');
    } finally {
        _logNugetToolInstallerStartupVariables(nugetVersion, checkLatest, nuGetPath, msBuildSemVer)
    }
}

function _logNugetToolInstallerStartupVariables(nugetVersion: string, 
    checkLatest: boolean, 
    nuGetPath: string,
    msBuildSemVer: string) {
    try {
        const telem = {
            "NUGET_EXE_TOOL_PATH_ENV_VAR": taskLib.getVariable(nuGetGetter.NUGET_EXE_TOOL_PATH_ENV_VAR),
            "DEFAULT_NUGET_VERSION": DEFAULT_NUGET_VERSION,
            "isCheckLatestEnabled": checkLatest,
            "requestedNuGetVersionSpec": taskLib.getInput('versionSpec', false),
            "nuGetPath": nuGetPath,
            "nugetVersion": nugetVersion,
            "msBuildVersion": msBuildSemVer
        };
        telemetry.emitTelemetry("Packaging", "NuGetToolInstaller", telem);
    } catch (err) {
        taskLib.debug(`Unable to log NuGet Tool Installer task init telemetry. Err:(${err})`);
    }
}

run();
```

Take a quick read of the code and you'll notice two differences:

One is that some innocuous variables are defined differently, and the other is that the logic of getting the nuget.exe version is different.

See how the 'getNuGet' method is implemented:

## NuGetToolGetter.ts

```
import * as toolLib from 'azure-pipelines-tool-lib/tool';
import * as taskLib from 'azure-pipelines-task-lib/task';
import * as restm from 'typed-rest-client/RestClient';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as semver from 'semver';
import * as commandHelper from './CommandHelper';
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as os from "os";

interface INuGetTools {
    nugetexe: INuGetVersionInfo[]
}

interface INuGetVersionInfo {
    version: string,
    url: string,
    stage: NuGetReleaseStage
}

enum NuGetReleaseStage
{
    "EarlyAccessPreview",
    "Released",
    "ReleasedAndBlessed"
}

const NUGET_TOOL_NAME: string = 'NuGet';
const NUGET_EXE_FILENAME: string = 'nuget.exe';
const NUGET_SCRIPT_FILENAME: string = 'nuget';

export const FORCE_NUGET_4_0_0: string  = 'FORCE_NUGET_4_0_0';
export const NUGET_VERSION_4_0_0: string = '4.0.0';
export const NUGET_VERSION_4_0_0_PATH_SUFFIX: string = 'NuGet/4.0.0/';
export const DEFAULT_NUGET_VERSION: string = '4.1.0';
export const DEFAULT_NUGET_PATH_SUFFIX: string = 'NuGet/4.1.0/';
export const NUGET_EXE_TOOL_PATH_ENV_VAR: string = 'NuGetExeToolPath';

export async function getNuGet(versionSpec: string, checkLatest?: boolean, addNuGetToPath?: boolean): Promise<string> {
    if (toolLib.isExplicitVersion(versionSpec)) {
        // Check latest doesn't make sense when explicit version
        checkLatest = false;
        taskLib.debug('Exact match expected on version: ' + versionSpec);
    }
    else {
        taskLib.debug('Query match expected on version: ' + versionSpec);
        console.log(taskLib.loc("Info_ExpectBehaviorChangeWhenUsingVersionQuery"));
    }

    // If we're not checking latest, check the cache first
    let toolPath: string;
    if (!checkLatest) {
        taskLib.debug('Trying to get tool from local cache');
        toolPath = toolLib.findLocalTool(NUGET_TOOL_NAME, versionSpec);
    }

    let localVersions: string[] = toolLib.findLocalToolVersions(NUGET_TOOL_NAME);
    let version: string = toolLib.evaluateVersions(localVersions, versionSpec);

    if (toolPath) {
        // If here, then we're not checking latest and we found the tool in cache
        console.log(taskLib.loc("Info_ResolvedToolFromCache", version));
    }
    else {
        let versionInfo: INuGetVersionInfo = await getLatestMatchVersionInfo(versionSpec);

        // There is a local version which matches the spec yet we found one on dist.nuget.org
        // which is different, so we're about to change the version which was used
        if (version && version !== versionInfo.version) {
            taskLib.warning(taskLib.loc("Warning_UpdatingNuGetVersion", versionInfo.version, version));
        }

        version = versionInfo.version;
        taskLib.debug('Found the following version from the list: ' + version);

        if (!versionInfo.url)
        {
            taskLib.error(taskLib.loc("Error_NoUrlWasFoundWhichMatches", version));
            throw new Error(taskLib.loc("Error_NuGetToolInstallerFailer", NUGET_TOOL_NAME));
        }

        toolPath = toolLib.findLocalTool(NUGET_TOOL_NAME, version);

        if (!toolPath) {
            taskLib.debug('Downloading version: ' + version);
            let downloadPath: string = await toolLib.downloadTool(versionInfo.url);

            taskLib.debug('Caching file');
            toolLib.cacheFile(downloadPath, NUGET_EXE_FILENAME, NUGET_TOOL_NAME, version);
        }
    }

    console.log(taskLib.loc("Info_UsingVersion", version));
    toolPath= toolLib.findLocalTool(NUGET_TOOL_NAME, version);

    if (addNuGetToPath){
        console.log(taskLib.loc("Info_UsingToolPath", toolPath));
        toolLib.prependPath(toolPath);
    }

    let fullNuGetPath: string = path.join(toolPath, NUGET_EXE_FILENAME);
    taskLib.setVariable(NUGET_EXE_TOOL_PATH_ENV_VAR, fullNuGetPath);

    // create a nuget posix script for nuget exe in non-windows agents
    if (os.platform() !== "win32") {
        generateNugetScript(toolPath, fullNuGetPath);
    }
    
    return fullNuGetPath;
}

function generateNugetScript(nugetToolPath: string, nugetExePath: string) {
    var nugetScriptPath = path.join(nugetToolPath, NUGET_SCRIPT_FILENAME);

    if (fs.existsSync(nugetScriptPath)) {
        taskLib.debug(`nugetScriptPath already exist at ${nugetScriptPath}, skipped.`)
    } else {
        taskLib.debug(`create nugetScriptPath ${nugetScriptPath}`);

        fs.writeFile(
            nugetScriptPath,
            `#!/bin/sh\nmono ${nugetExePath} "$@"\n`,
            (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    taskLib.debug("Writing nuget script failed with error: " + err);
                } else {
                    // give read and execute permissions to everyone
                    fs.chmodSync(nugetScriptPath, "500");
                    taskLib.debug("Writing nuget script succeeded");
                }
            }
        );
    }
}

function pathExistsAsFile(path: string) {
    try {
        return taskLib.stats(path).isFile();
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}

// Based on code in Tasks\Common\MSBuildHelpers\msbuildhelpers.ts
export async function getMSBuildVersionString(): Promise<string> {
    const msbuild2019Path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/MSBuild/Current/Bin/msbuild.exe';
    const msbuild2022Path = 'C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/MSBuild/Current/Bin/msbuild.exe';
    
    let version: string;
    let path: string = taskLib.which('msbuild', false);

    // Hmmm... it's not on the path. Can we find it directly?
    if (!path && (taskLib.osType() === 'Windows_NT'))  {
        if (pathExistsAsFile(msbuild2022Path)) {
            taskLib.debug('Falling back to VS2022 install path');
            path = msbuild2022Path;
        } else if (pathExistsAsFile(msbuild2019Path)) {
            taskLib.debug('Falling back to VS2019 install path');
            path = msbuild2019Path;
        }
    }

    if (path) {
        taskLib.debug('Found msbuild.exe at: ' + path);
        const getVersionTool = taskLib.tool(path);
        getVersionTool.arg(['/version', '/nologo']);
        getVersionTool.on('stdout', (data: string) => {
            if (data) {
                version = data.toString().trim();
                taskLib.debug('Found msbuild version: ' + version);
            }
        });
        await getVersionTool.exec();
        taskLib.debug('Finished running msbuild /version /nologo');
    }
    return version;
}

export async function getMSBuildVersion(): Promise<semver.SemVer> {
    const version = await getMSBuildVersionString();
    return semver.coerce(version);
}

export async function cacheBundledNuGet(
    cachedVersionToUse?: string,
    nugetPathSuffix?: string): Promise<string> {
    if (cachedVersionToUse == null) {
        // Attempt to match nuget.exe version with msbuild.exe version
        const msbuildSemVer = await getMSBuildVersion();
        if (msbuildSemVer && semver.gte(msbuildSemVer, '16.8.0')) {
            taskLib.debug('Snapping to v5.8.0');
            cachedVersionToUse = '5.8.0';
            nugetPathSuffix = 'NuGet/5.8.0/';
        } else if (msbuildSemVer && semver.gte(msbuildSemVer, '16.5.0')) {
            taskLib.debug('Snapping to v5.4.0');
            cachedVersionToUse = '5.4.0';
            nugetPathSuffix = 'NuGet/5.4.0/';
        } else {
            cachedVersionToUse = DEFAULT_NUGET_VERSION;
        }
    }

    if (nugetPathSuffix == null) {
        nugetPathSuffix = DEFAULT_NUGET_PATH_SUFFIX;
    }

    if (taskLib.getVariable(FORCE_NUGET_4_0_0) &&
        taskLib.getVariable(FORCE_NUGET_4_0_0).toLowerCase() === "true"){
        cachedVersionToUse = NUGET_VERSION_4_0_0;
        nugetPathSuffix = NUGET_VERSION_4_0_0_PATH_SUFFIX;
    }

    if (!toolLib.findLocalTool(NUGET_TOOL_NAME, cachedVersionToUse)) {
        taskLib.debug(`Placing bundled NuGet.exe ${cachedVersionToUse} in tool lib cache`);

        let bundledNuGetLocation: string = getBundledNuGet_Location([nugetPathSuffix]);
        await toolLib.cacheFile(bundledNuGetLocation, NUGET_EXE_FILENAME, NUGET_TOOL_NAME, cachedVersionToUse);
    }

    return cachedVersionToUse;
}

function GetRestClientOptions(): restm.IRequestOptions
{
    let options: restm.IRequestOptions = <restm.IRequestOptions>{};
    options.responseProcessor = (obj: any) => {
        return obj['nuget.exe'];
    }
    return options;
}

async function getLatestMatchVersionInfo(versionSpec: string): Promise<INuGetVersionInfo> {
    taskLib.debug('Querying versions list');

    let versionsUrl = 'https://dist.nuget.org/tools.json';
    let proxyRequestOptions = {
        proxy: taskLib.getHttpProxyConfiguration(versionsUrl)
    };
    let rest: restm.RestClient = new restm.RestClient('vsts-tasks/NuGetToolInstaller', undefined, undefined, proxyRequestOptions);

    let nugetVersions: INuGetVersionInfo[] = (await rest.get<INuGetVersionInfo[]>(versionsUrl, GetRestClientOptions())).result;
    // x.stage is the string representation of the enum, NuGetReleaseStage.Value = number, NuGetReleaseStage[NuGetReleaseStage.Value] = string, NuGetReleaseStage[x.stage] = number
    let releasedVersions: INuGetVersionInfo[] = nugetVersions.filter(x => x.stage.toString() !== NuGetReleaseStage[NuGetReleaseStage.EarlyAccessPreview]);
    let versionStringsFromDist: string[] = releasedVersions.map(x => x.version);

    let version: string = toolLib.evaluateVersions(versionStringsFromDist, versionSpec);
    if (!version)
    {
        taskLib.error(taskLib.loc("Error_NoVersionWasFoundWhichMatches", versionSpec));
        taskLib.error(taskLib.loc("Info_AvailableVersions", releasedVersions.map(x => x.version).join("; ")));
        throw new Error(taskLib.loc("Error_NuGetToolInstallerFailer", NUGET_TOOL_NAME));
    }

    return releasedVersions.find(x => x.version === version);
}

function getBundledNuGet_Location(nugetPaths: string[]): string {
    let taskNodeModulesPath: string = path.dirname(path.dirname(__dirname));
    let taskRootPath: string = path.dirname(taskNodeModulesPath);
    const toolPath = commandHelper.locateTool("NuGet",
    <commandHelper.LocateOptions>{
        root: taskRootPath,
        searchPath: nugetPaths,
        toolFilenames: ['NuGet.exe', 'nuget.exe'],
    });

    return toolPath;
}
```

So to sum up briefly, the new version of the task can achieve getting the latest version of nuget.exe by default

**NuGetToolInstaller@0:**

[image]

**NuGetToolInstaller@1:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Never thought to look at the source. I will bear this in mind to do so in future.

Comment: @kevins1966 Does my explanation of the differences answered your question?